# Program to delay audio output

Tags: mac, audio

I have a video that has audio several seconds in front of what it should be. I'm looking for an independent program that will delay the sound output. Is such a thing possible and more importantly is it free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/). You can adjust the audio during video playback. Perfect for when you have sync issues.

With the most recent version of VLC (Version 1.1.9) the keys to adjust the audio during playback are:

g - Audio delay up

f - Audio delay down

Comment: So VLC will do it for all video, including video in a browser like youtube? I was looking for an independent prgram.

Comment: No, browser plugins are controlled internally. I don't know of anything that can fix the sync on youtube or other things. That's your flash plugin misbehaving.